# Deleting object from AWS bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As the [official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/undelete-objects.html) says when we enable versioning on bucket, deleted objects can be restored as only delete marker will be created.

When objects will be actually deleted then?

As if deleting them only created delete marker, they will still consume place in bucket, how many days they will be present in bucket after deleting?

Answer (score 2):

If Versioning is enabled on a bucket, objects will *not* be deleted.

- Deleting the object will merely add a **delete marker**
- All versions of an object will be charged for storage space
- However, you can **delete a specific version** of the object
- If all *versions* of a document and the *delete marker* are deleted, then the object is fully deleted

If versioning is *not* enabled, then deleting an object will immediately delete it.

You can create [lifecycle rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) that can delete objects, or object versions, after a defined period of time.

Answer (score 0):

It will be there forever, unless you manually delete all the versions and the deletion marker. You can manually delete it by going tot he bucket, on versions, click "Show", then all the versions and deletion marker will be shown.  You can delete them afterwards.